# What is the best case for this function?

Tags: java, performance, max, big-o

```
/* Returns the largest integer in the array */
int CompareToAll(int array[], int n)
{
   int i, j;
   bool isMax;

  /* Make sure that there is at least one element in the array. */
  if (n <= 0)
   return -1;

  for (i = n-1; i > 0; i--) 
  {
    isMax = true;
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) 
    {
      /* See if any value is greater. */
      if (array[j] > array[i])
      { 
        isMax = false; /* array[i] is not the largest value. */
        break;
      }
    }
      /* If isMax is true, no larger value exists; array[i] is max. */
      if (isMax) break;
   }
  return array[i];
}
```

I read this code somewhere and it said that the best case is when max element is at the beginning of the array. Which is right since it will break out of the 2nd loop everytime it compares to the first element so n comparisons. But if the max element is at the end won't it still be the best case? Since the isMax flag will be true once it iterates through all the n elements after the first run of the 2nd for loop? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That's not valid Java. Even if it was, it would still be incorrect (try finding the max of `[2, 1, 3]`).

Comment: This is one crazy way to find the maximum (which is what the function appears to do).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch : I agree with you. But the book stated that the best case is when the max element is in the beginning of the array. The worst case is when the element is at the end of the array. Which I disagree with! I feel the best case happens in both cases

Comment: @NPE: Lol I agree. But this is how you understand what is crazy and what not

Comment: @JanŽegklitz Fine, but in this particular case arguing about the notation some third party commentator made to a particular example from an unnamed author seems counter productive. Regardless, OP's question seems to contain a strong claim - is it falsifiable?

Answer (score 3):

There is so much wrong with this code, it's hard to know where to start, but as you present it as third party code and have a specific question - let's take a look

```
/* Returns the largest integer in the array */
int CompareToAll(int array[], int n)
```

That's not Java and won't compile - let's assume it means `int CompareToAll(int[] array, int n)`

```
 /* Make sure that there is at least one element in the array. */
 if (n <= 0)
     return -1;
```

This implies that n is the length of the array, but there is no check that `n` really is the length of `array`.  Consider calling `CompareToAll(new int[]{}, 100)` or `CompareToAll(null, 100)`, the code will fall in an Exception ridden heap.

Next, consider the logic assuming that `n == array.length`.  We have `i` running down the array from last element to first, with `j` running from first to the last on every iteration of `i`.  The inner loop will break as soon as it finds an element greater than `array[i]`, and the code will finally terminate if and only if `array[i]` is greater than every other member of `array`.  Therefore, the assertion that the best case is when the max is at the first position of the array is true, but not complete.  The best case will also be, as the OP suggests, when the max element is in the last position of the array, in which case `n` checks will be performed.

This is really bad code and an assertion that doesn't cover every case.  OP suggests in comments it is from a book.  Unless this is presented as an exercise in checking whether a statement is complete, I recommend a new book.

Comment: I second that recommendation and suggest a good ol' book burning for the current one.

Comment: Thanks @j. It clarifies my confusion.